# Wrap the text inside a <div> using JQuery

Tags: jquery, regex

I'm working on replacing a particular text with a  wrapping that particular text. Anyhow I'm confused in doing so. I'm able to find the particular words matching my scenario. But, I need to replace them inside a

### Here is my html

```
<small>
    Size: M<div class="item-devider"></div> 
    checkbox_test: Yes<div class="item-devider"></div>
    I don't mind about color: No<div class="item-devider"></div> 
    test: No<div class="item-devider"></div> 
    test_group: select1<div class="item-devider"></div>
</small>
```

### JQuery

```
$('.item-devider').map(function(){
    var text = this.previousSibling.nodeValue.indexOf(': No') == -1 ?  undefined  : this.previousSibling.nodeValue;              
    if(text!= undefined) {

    }
});
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/EwNRJ/1135/

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
var texts = $('.item-devider').map(function(){
    return this.previousSibling.nodeValue.indexOf(': No') > -1;        
});
```

This above code will return the div which is having a string in its previous position which contains the text ': No'

And also try this too,

```
var texts = $('#sample small').contents().filter(function(){
    return $(this).text().indexOf(': No') > -1;     
}).wrap('<div/>');
```

### **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/EwNRJ/1134/)**

Comment: Hey, thats woking fine. It returns either true or false. Can you tell me how can I wrap the only the text which returns true inside a <div>?

Comment: Thanks a lotttttttttttt :)

Answer (score 0):

Return `undefined` in the callback of `.map` will remove the elements not needed.

```
var texts = $('.item-devider').map(function(){
    return this.previousSibling.nodeValue.indexOf(': No') == -1 ?  undefined  : this.previousSibling.nodeValue;
}).get();
```

**[The working demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/EwNRJ/1132/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
$('#sample small').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3 && $.trim(this.nodeValue).indexOf(': No') > -1;
}).wrap('<div class="highlight" />');
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EwNRJ/1137/)**